# React Next.js build 2 themed apps from 1 app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, build

I have a single app and want to build 2 packages each with its own theme served via the public folder.

App theme folder structure:

```
src/
  themes/
    meetings/
      assets/
    weddings/
      assets/
```

How do I configure next so at build time I get a single theme in the public/ folder via a flag or some other mechanism?

Desired public/ folder output when running `next build --flag weddings` or whatever the proper syntax would be:

```
public/
  theme/
    weddings/
      assets/
```

This way my components could reference `/theme/${themeName}/assets/...` to pull in specific images, icons, text, etc. with the same file name.

Everything that I have searched for showed info for dark/light mode theme toggling, which is not what I am looking for, I just want to build and ship an individually themed app from a single app to host on 2 different websites.

FYI - I already have a mechanism to determine and set the `themeName` to be consumed in the React components, just looking for the `How To` in next.js config.

Comment: It has been a wondered me to. Yes, everything I have searched for has shown information for dark/light mode themes, but I didn't ask for this. I guess I will not find a response.